# IFileSaveDialog - choosing folders in Windows 7

Tags: winapi, windows-7, folderbrowserdialog

In Vista, I have been using an `IFileSaveDialog` to let users pick a "save-as" folder. Users export a folder of images, say, and need to choose a new or existing target folder.

Briefly, the code goes like this:

```
IFileSaveDialog* dialog; // created
dialog->SetOptions(FOS_PICKFOLDERS);
dialog->Show(NULL);
dialog->GetResult(&shellItem)
```

In Windows 7, the `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` option appears to have been disallowed (and is marked as such in [the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775708%28VS.85%29.aspx)).  The return value on the `SetOptions` call is `E_INVALIDARG`.  If I use a IFileOpenDialog, I'm allowed to set the folders option, but the user is prompted with an error when choosing a nonexistent folder (despite my setting flags suggesting not to do this).

Is there an alternate way to get the new `IFileDialog` to act as a "save folder" dialog?

[To head off some comments, the SHBrowseForFolder API still exists, but is still not an acceptable solution for our UI deciders.]

Comment: Amusingly, the Windows Team used this flag in a sample on their blog back in April!

http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/archive/2009/04/16/light-up-with-windows-7-libraries.aspx

Comment: And a comment from kazoobrewer telling them it no longer works.  I guess that would be you then...

Comment: Sometimes it feels like you're the only developer using an API in the wild...

Comment: Archive of Windows 7 Developers Blog entry [**Light Up with Windows 7 Libraries**](https://archive.vn/wip/vx42I)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this can be found in the documentation:

> [`FOS_PICKFOLDERS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-_fileopendialogoptions): Present the Open dialog offering a choice of folders rather than files.

Using `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` for *"save"* was never supposed to be supported - but Vista didn't enforce it. Use `IFileOpenDialog` instead and you're good to go.
You are picking an existing folder (not specifying a folder to create), so open was always the correct choice.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't played around with the Windows 7 dialogs yet, but downloaded the [Windows® API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) just this morning as I am implementing the Thumbnail Toolbar and Icon Overlay in the application I am working on.  It'll probably point you in the right direction.