# Allowing IFileOpenDialog to pick a folder that doesn't exist yet

Tags: c++, winapi, folderbrowserdialog

I'm trying to create a dialog to select a new folder to save files into. The [IFileOpenDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class works great except that it won't allow a new folder to be picked.

I.e. "Folder: C:\existings\new-folder" in the bottom of the dialog pops up the following message:

> new-folder
>   Path does not exist.
>   Check the path and try again.

Here's the code I've got:

```
IFileDialog* fileDialog
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
    IID_PPV_ARGS(&fileDialog));

DWORD options;
fileDialog->GetOptions(&options);

options &= ~FOS_FILEMUSTEXIST;  
options &= ~FOS_PATHMUSTEXIST;
fileDialog->SetOptions(options | FOS_PICKFOLDERS);

fileDialog->Show(parentWindow);
```

Any pointers or hacks would be appreciated! Thanks!

---

To quote Michael from this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626993/ifilesavedialog-choosing-folders-in-windows-7):

> [To head off some comments, the SHBrowseForFolder API still exists, but is still not an acceptable solution for our UI deciders.]

The same applies here...

Comment: This begs the question of why you're using an open dialog to select where to save something...

Comment: Deanna, I'm trying to replace a Java select file dialog with a native version so it has to match the original behaviour (unfortunately that means the folder pick dialog is out). With the Java dialog you can browse to a folder and type in the name for a new folder to create (Imaging an archive application where you want to pick a new folder to save a bunch of files into). Trying to do that with IFileOpenDialog fails if FOS_PICKFOLDERS is used.

Comment: Can't they just click the native "create folder" button and select it?

Comment: That's possible, its just not as nice ;-) Imagine if every time you wanted to save a file you had to click "create file" then select it.

Comment: @Deanna It's like a **Save As** dialog. The user is trying to specify where something **will** go; not where something **is**.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use **CLSID_FileSaveDialog** instead of **CLSID_FileOpenDialog**.  And possibly make use of [IFileSaveDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in addition to the base class IFileDialog.

Comment: It looks like the save dialog no longer supports FOS_PICKFOLDERS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626993/ifilesavedialog-choosing-folders-in-windows-7

Comment: It was never supported in `IFileSaveDialog` to begin with, as it is an `IFileOpenDialog` flag.

Answer (score 1):

As you're selecting a folder, you could use the folder picker dialog.
This, with the right flags, has a "create" button at the bottom and a text entry allowing you to specifiy a non existant path.

Comment: On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115%28VS.85%29.aspx) it sounds like SHBrowseForFolder is discouraged for new apps: `For Windows Vista or later, it is recommended that you use IFileDialog with the FOS_PICKFOLDERS option rather than the SHBrowseForFolder function. This uses the Open Files dialog in pick folders mode and is the preferred implementation.`